# Issue with makeprg Shell Script $? Variable

Tags: quickfix, shell, makeprg, make

I have the following `.vimrc`:

```
let &makeprg="./run-tests"
```

The contents of `run-tests`:

```
#!/bin/sh

error_file=$(mktemp)
coverage run --source "$PWD" --branch -m pytest tests/ >"$error_file" 2>&1
if test $?; then
  coverage report --show-missing
else
  cat "$error_file"
fi
```

If the tests pass, I want to only show the coverage information. If the tests fail, I only want to show the test information.

However, on both passing and failing tests, `$?` is always 0, i.e. a success.
If I copy and paste the `coverage run ...` command in the terminal and manually inspect `echo $?` I do get 0 for success and 1 for failing tests.
It seems that the value of `$?` is being altered by some other command that Vim is executing in the `makeprg` pipeline.

How best to resolve this?

Comment: Your script would run in a separate process (a subshell) and use of `$?` within won't be influenced by whatever happens external to the script. Instead of running `coverage run ...` directly/manually you should try running the script itself. Maybe save `$?` in a variable immediately after `coverage` (e.g. `result=$?`) then, say, `echo "Result is $result"` before doing `if test $result; then ...`. Then at least you'll know for sure what it's value was in the script.

Comment: It’s a bit of an anti pattern to just test the exit code this way, when you can do `if command …`. @BLayer is correct: vim cannot interfere with the execution of the script as you describe. Perhaps you misunderstood the test builtin? Does the script work outside of vim? I suspect this belongs somewhere more related to programming than here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having here is that the `test` command with a single argument will by default check whether or not that's an empty string. So, in your case, it's taking the `0` and looking at it as a `"0"` string, which is not empty (it has one character), but the same with a fail error code, like `1`, which it sees as `"1"` and it's also non-empty.

For your code to work and properly check whether the `coverage run` succeeded, what you need here is `test $? = 0` instead.